# delete the lastest row in BK

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have in the table policies, where BK for them is

```
VIN + ProgramCode + ValidFrom
```

Structure of the table is

```
ID, ProgramCode, VIN, ValidFrom, CreationDate
```

The problem is that I need to keep only the policy with a unique `VIN` and the latest value of `Creation_date`, the rest need to be deleted. I don't have an idea what query I should use for it using group by.

Comment: BK? Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

use window function `row_number`

```
delete from
    (
    select * ,row_number() over(partition by ProgramCode, VIN, ValidFrom order by Creation_date desc) as rn
    ) as t where t.rn!=1
```

Note: for large data set it is better to keep unike data in new  table and  then delete old table then rename the new table in old name